# How to add specific property to element and keep original design of group?

Tags: html, css

I have trouble to add properties like position, margins etc to `<div>` element which is part of another `<div>` that have style that I want to keep.

Here is the link to screenshot of web page [image: web page]

I have problems with this gray transparent area, it is formatted to have re-sizable height, depend on elements in it and when I add positioning of another div ("customProperties") in CSS, original CSS is not applying (on screenshot you can see element above and belove the bottom line of gray area).

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrap">
    (...)
    <div id="customProperties">
        <ul>el1</ul>
        <ul>el2</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sorry if there is similar question, but I just can't find solution...

Comment: Let's see that CSS...

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: Without the proper html and css, it's hard to come up with a solution, or even understand the problem. please share the same or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/tk4Zw/2/

Comment: remove `position: absolute;` from ID `#customProperties`

Comment: Well, that do work on jsfiddle, but nothing happened in original code...

Comment: @SyDaemon would be better if you explain what you're trying to do and how the end result should look like. As of now, all the community can reply back is according to the info you provide… none can read your mind.. :)

Comment: My bad, I edited backup file instead of file in work location. :)
Everything is OK now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've applied `position:absolute` for `#customProperties` which takes the element out of normal flow. Hence it's parents size won't grow automatically.

*side note:*

```
<ul>el1</ul>
<ul>el2</ul>
```

*is not semantically correct, it should be*

```
<ul>
  <li>el1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>el2</li>
</ul>
```